# Определение переменных в одну строку

Tags: javascript

Есть способ определить эти переменные

```
const a = "a"
const b = "b"
```

В одну строку типо

```
const a,b
a = "a"
b = "b"
```

Comment: const a = "123", b = "123"

Comment: Есть, но не стоит по некоторым причинам. Например в удаление и добавление  -  в гите будет отображаться совсем не то, что на самом деле.  Само удаление ненужной переменной - дольше и неуклюже, чем просто Ctrl+X на строке сделать и прочие разработчиские нюансы

Answer (score 1):

Да, вот пример, как это делается:

```js
const a = 5, b = 8;

console.log(a, b);
```

**UPD**:

С `const` необходимо объявлять все переменные сразу иначе вылезет ошибка. Это связано с тем, что переменную типа `const` нельзя изменить после объявления. Чтобы часть переменных оставалась без присвоенного значения, необходимо использовать `let` :

```js
let a, b = 'abc', c = 3;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Comment: А если мне понадобится инициализировать переменные сейчас, а задать их потом, можно как-то оставить эти поля пустыми?

Comment: @Momav для это используйте `let`

Comment: @Momav, тогда это будет не `const`

Answer (score -1):

```
const [a, b] = ["a", "b"]

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Почему заминусил?